# jquery to select parents node

Tags: jquery

To find form element from the element which triggered event. I use following code. but it seems crazy to me.

Is there a better way doing this?

```
$("#xx").click(function(event) {
    var testValue = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().data("test");
});
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems crazy to me that you have a form element with seven levels of nesting in it - sounds like a case of divitis. Note that the `attr("#firstForm")` at the end will try to return the value associated with an attribute named "#firstForm", it's not trying to find a parent matching "#firstForm" as a selector.

Comment: sorry for my messy question I edited it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crazy is right. :D

`$(this).closest('#firstForm')` should do this for you.

Comment: Note that if the id of this is firstForm then .closest will return this

Comment: Good point. Must also be noted that if we're really working with just IDs here, then it'd be quicker to just select via ID, actually.

Comment: aaaaaaaaand just reading through the answers and I saw that you answered the exact same thing. :D throwing you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is valid then simply do

```
$("#firstForm")
```

ids are unique (assuming valid HTML)

Comment: @PatrickJeon nw. It doesn't affect the solution either. If you know the id why not simply select the id? If the id is not unique why not fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#xx").click(function(event) {
    $(this).parents('#YourId').attr("firstForm");
});
```

for reference see this link : http://api.jquery.com/parents/